# How to tell from the code which language to deploy?

Tags: magento2, deploy

If you don't have access to Magento 2 backend, how to tell from the code which language to deploy?
For example how do I know I should deploy this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

or

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_CA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have access to the server shell, so you can install n98-magerun 2 https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2.

You can then

- either create a new admin user with a password of your choice
- or perform a SQL query against the Magento 2 database to find all locales:

`php n98-magerun2.phar db:query "SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'general/locale/code'"`